# Tricky system of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of differential equations that I'm really struggling to solve

$L_1(di_2/dt)+(R_1+R_2)i_2+R_1i_3=E(t)$

$L_2(di_3/dt)+R_1i_2+R_1i_3 = E(t)$

$R_1=6\Omega$, $R_2=5\Omega$, $L_1=1h$, $L_2=1h$, $E(t)=48sin(t)V$, $i_2(0)=0$, $i_3(0)=0$

I've never dealt with a system that is this complex and I'm generally just too overwhelmed to start this system. Anything helps.

Thanks.

Comment: What methods of solving a DE system do you know?

Comment: I only know solution via Laplace transform.